# Running two websites with two subdomains httpd

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain

I have a domain `example.com` with two subdomains: `website.example.com` and `cloud.example.com`. I set an A-Record for both of them to my server's IP address.

my server is a VPS with centos7 and has two directories below `/var/www/html/` for each of the domains:

- `/var/www/html/website.example.com/` contains all wordpress files
- `/var/www/html/cloud/` contains all files for ownCloud.

I enhanced my httpd.conf to contain:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website.example.com
ServerName www.website.example.com
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:81
<VirtualHost *:81>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cloud
ServerName www.cloud.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I restart httpd and run wget i get the following responses:

- `my.vps.ip.address` -> response from wordpress site
- `my.vps.ip.address:80` -> response from wordpress site
- `my.vps.ip.address:81` -> response from cloud site
- `website.example.com` -> response from wordpress site
- `cloud.example.com` -> response from wordpress site.

This results to the browser experience -> When i enter `website.example.com` in my browser I get on my wordpress site. But when I enter `cloud.example.com` I also get on my wordpress site instead of the owncloud site.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set your `ServerName` to `www.cloud.example.com`, but try to access it with `cloud.example.com`. Also you forgot the port 81.

Either set it to `cloud.example.com` or add an `ServerAlias cloud.example.com`.

You don't need to set the `cloud.example.com` on a different port. Apache is perfectly capable of handling different VirtualHosts on the same port. Just leave it on port 80.

It should look like this:

```
Listen 80
# Listen 81
# Just stay on port 80, don't make it more complicated for the clients

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
# NameVirtualHost *:80
# This is not needed anymore with Apache 2.4

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/website.example.com
ServerName website.example.com
ServerAlias www.website.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/cloud
ServerName cloud.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I adapted my httpd conf according to your comment. now the wget for cloud.example.com does return the correct response. Only problem is that I cannot get the correct response using chrome.

cloud.example.com in chrome still leads to website.example.com. Entering the IP in chrome leads to website.example.com

Comment: Did you restart apache? Did you clear your browser cache? If you access apache with a hostname that is not configured (like you do when you use the IP) apache uses the first listed VirtualHost. See [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/949512/apache-allowing-http-access-when-should-be-redirected-to-https/949514#949514) for details.

Comment: I added an example configuration to the answer

Comment: I now use the full configuration provided by you. still I can only access the website.example.com , while cloud.example.com gets redirected. I assume, the problem lays in my DNS configuration. I setup the two subdomains in my domain provider, though my server is hosted somewhere else and probably the linking between the host /server names isnt working out, but actually i have no clue how to fix that. As of now both have the same A-Record -> Ip address of the vps. Does my vps need some dns configuration or something?

Comment: Redirection does not happen via DNS. If you get an actual redirect (the URL in your browser changes from `cloud` to `website`) you have something else configured in your Apache that you haven't shown yet.

Comment: this redirection with url is exactly whats happening, also the order of my virtual hosts does not have any effect

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess files that do a redirect? Is OwnCloud configured to use `website.example.com` instead of `cloud.example.com`?

Comment: it works now.
it was the .htaccess on my domain. 
Though before it did not work out so my really problem was the virtual hosts config. Thank you for your help!